# ExpectedError: Error: Max connection attempts reached

Tags: node.js, adobe-brackets

[image]

I've tried what it is suggested in the warning below, but no joy: I just get another warning that says Brackets was unable to remove the extension.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/zaggino/brackets-git/issues/410) that I have also checked.

How do I get Brackets back to normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always remove Brackets extension by deleting its folder in the [Extension Folder](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Extension-Locations#user-extensions-folder).